How to wire a repurposed ac motor
I have an old garage door opener that I would like to repurpose. I would like to bypass the normal garage door logic and add an on-off-on switch. When switched to on1 rotates in direction 1, when switched to on2 rotates in direction 2.
The wiring is fairly atypical with how the capacitor is wired. Any advice on how to add the switch?



Should be rewired like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thank you for the answer! I noticed on your diagram and the other diagram neutral and line are different. Does it matter which one is connected to what side?

Functionally, no. It does not matter. But from a standpoint of safety (and regulations), you want to interrupt the live wire with the switch. In other words, you don't want a situation where the appliance is "live" without a neutral. Cause then, when the device is off, it's never "unpowered".



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Modified switching.
If you can't find an ON-OFF-ON 3-position switch then use a 2-position switch for direction and another switch for ON-OFF.
